# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError: indices[40] = 2000 0 is not in [0, 20000)

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I was runnig this code (https://github.com/monkut/tensorflow_chatbot main code in execute.py) on my Windows7 with python 3.5 and tensorflow r0.12 cpu and an error occured after just 300 steps. Then I tried to change the vocabulary size to 30000 and set a checkpiont every 100 steps. With 1 layer of 128 units the error occured after 3900 steps and with 3 layers of 256 units it occured after 5400 steps.
What kind of error is that? Is there a way to solve it?

Error:

```
>> Mode : train

Preparing data in working_dir/
Creating vocabulary working_dir/vocab20000.enc from data/train.enc
  processing line 100000
>> Full Vocabulary Size : 45408
>>>> Vocab Truncated to: 20000
Creating vocabulary working_dir/vocab20000.dec from data/train.dec
  processing line 100000
>> Full Vocabulary Size : 44271
>>>> Vocab Truncated to: 20000
Tokenizing data in data/train.enc
  tokenizing line 100000
Tokenizing data in data/train.dec
  tokenizing line 100000
Tokenizing data in data/test.enc
Creating 3 layers of 256 units.
Created model with fresh parameters.
Reading development and training data (limit: 0).
  reading data line 100000
global step 300 learning rate 0.5000 step-time 3.34 perplexity 377.45
  eval: bucket 0 perplexity 96.25
  eval: bucket 1 perplexity 210.94
  eval: bucket 2 perplexity 267.86
  eval: bucket 3 perplexity 365.77
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", l
ine 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", l
ine 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl
.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[40] = 2000
0 is not in [0, 20000)
         [[Node: model_with_buckets/sequence_loss_3/sequence_loss_by_example/sam
pled_softmax_loss_28/embedding_lookup_1 = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_F
LOAT, _class=["loc:@proj_b"], validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/rep
lica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](proj_b/read, model_with_buckets/sequence_loss_3/sequence_l
oss_by_example/sampled_softmax_loss_28/concat)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execute.py", line 352, in <module>
    train()
  File "execute.py", line 180, in train
    target_weights, bucket_id, False)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\Downloads\tensorflow_chatbot-master (1)\tensorflo
w_chatbot-master\seq2seq_model.py", line 230, in step
    outputs = session.run(output_feed, input_feed)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", l
ine 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", l
ine 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", l
ine 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", l
ine 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[40] = 2000
0 is not in [0, 20000)
         [[Node: model_with_buckets/sequence_loss_3/sequence_loss_by_example/sam
pled_softmax_loss_28/embedding_lookup_1 = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_F
LOAT, _class=["loc:@proj_b"], validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/rep
lica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](proj_b/read, model_with_buckets/sequence_loss_3/sequence_l
oss_by_example/sampled_softmax_loss_28/concat)]]

Caused by op 'model_with_buckets/sequence_loss_3/sequence_loss_by_example/sample
d_softmax_loss_28/embedding_lookup_1', defined at:
  File "execute.py", line 352, in <module>
    train()
  File "execute.py", line 148, in train
    model = create_model(sess, False)
  File "execute.py", line 109, in create_model
    gConfig['learning_rate_decay_factor'], forward_only=forward_only)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\Downloads\tensorflow_chatbot-master (1)\tensorflo
w_chatbot-master\seq2seq_model.py", line 158, in __init__
    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\seq2seq.py", line
 1130, in model_with_buckets
    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function))
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\seq2seq.py", line
 1058, in sequence_loss
    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function))
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\seq2seq.py", line
 1022, in sequence_loss_by_example
    crossent = softmax_loss_function(logit, target)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\Downloads\tensorflow_chatbot-master (1)\tensorflo
w_chatbot-master\seq2seq_model.py", line 101, in sampled_loss
    self.target_vocab_size)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn.py", line 1412
, in sampled_softmax_loss
    name=name)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn.py", line 1184
, in _compute_sampled_logits
    all_b = embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(biases, all_ids)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\embedding_ops.py"
, line 110, in embedding_lookup
    validate_indices=validate_indices)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py"
, line 1293, in gather
    validate_indices=validate_indices, name=name)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_libr
ary.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", li
ne 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Python35 64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", li
ne 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[40] = 20000 is not in [0
, 20000)
         [[Node: model_with_buckets/sequence_loss_3/sequence_loss_by_example/sam
pled_softmax_loss_28/embedding_lookup_1 = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_F
LOAT, _class=["loc:@proj_b"], validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/rep
lica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](proj_b/read, model_with_buckets/sequence_loss_3/sequence_l
oss_by_example/sampled_softmax_loss_28/concat)]]
```

Comment: Looks like the error message tells you exactly what's wrong. `[0
, 20000)` indicates a [*left-closed, right-open interval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Classification_of_intervals), so 20000 is out of bounds.

Comment: try setting the vocab size to 20001 and tell give us the error message then.

Comment: This may take several hours before the error occurs. I will inform you when it will happen.
see error that occured with vocabulary size 30000 here (https://github.com/yellowbirdwithme/Error-InvalidArgument/blob/master/error%2030000.txt)

Comment: you can find error message for vocab size here https://github.com/yellowbirdwithme/Error-InvalidArgument/blob/master/error%2020001 
It is very similar

Comment: I am stuck with same error. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: It seems using virtualenv and tensorflow-gpu 0.12.0 solves the problem for me. It works without interruptions. The reason of this error is still unclear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems using virtualenv and tensorflow-gpu 0.12.0 solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `[)` means Inclusive Exclusive in interval notation. 
`[` means *including that number*. `(` means excluding that number. 
the same goes for right parentheses and brackets ie `]` & `)`. For example `[0,20000)`
means from Zero inclusive to 20000 not inclusive. Brackets mean "Yes include this" parenthesis mean "no, don't go all the way up to this number"

Comment: Yes, I understand. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: the entire code is here, main file is execute.py https://github.com/monkut/tensorflow_chatbot/blob/master/
code of the version of tensorflow I'm using is here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12

Comment: kk, but please check out my comment to your question